# Atom : open files from different location with single click

Tags: atom-editor

Is there any way to open selected files from different folders (apache/httpd/conf, apache/httpd/logs, magento/var/log) as if they are a single project ?  Should be able to close them with single button, and open with single button.

I tried couple of packages, but none found useful.

Basically am looking for functionality to open and close multiple files, whether its available as a project or multiple tab or  multiple files.

Comment: Are the folders in the same parent folder?

Comment: no, files can be anywhere from the system...